# How to find out reasons for process being killed and the source?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a simple .net 4.0 wcf server that I suspect is being kill by other process in the system. Normally in the dispose I'm logging that the server is shutting down but something there is nothing in the log so think the process is being killed.

I do not see anything in the win7 event viewer.

Is there something I can do to detect when and why the process is killed (and by whom)? Maybe with some low level OS monitoring?

Edit:
should add: some other process can intiate the server by starting the process. I don't have control over the other process and I'm told that the other process does not issue kill.

Edit2: is there a way to do "emergency logging" when a process is killed/abruptly exit? AppDomain.ProcessExit is not guaranteed to be called after all so is there other way to fo something like this?

Edit3: Also read this but didn't help a lot
http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2006/10/30/95435.aspx

strange that there is no way to get this info by the CLR/OS. I bet this is important information for debugging

Comment: Did you try, AppDomain.UnhandledException, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes I did. No exceptions are thrown.

Comment: Check if your application consumes un-expected memory? Most of the cases the error is logged in event veiwer, you should make sure that you are checking it correctly, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997769(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: Also checked. the server stay around 50-75 MB with a peak of 100MB. Added some additional info. 

thanks for suggestions :)

Comment: When is your process killed? After a specific action? Can you reproduce the error or does it occur completely randomly?

Comment: You could attempt to implement a Constrained Execution Region (CER) to take advantage of the reliability features in .Net - quick google search found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163716.aspx